# Speex echo canceler, initial state learning

Tags: signal-processing, speex

I rebuilding an existing product using the speex echo canceler (to replace an obsolete speakerphone solution). There is a strong feedback from the speaker to the microphone, both mounted in the same surface with the microphone only mounted in a rubber ring to damp some vibrations a bit. The echo canceler function fine when trained.

I try to give some kind of a chime before the connection is started to train the echo canceler. Are there any references about good training sounds? Or other initial training modes?

At this moment the sound level feels a bit low. I like to increase the amplifier (loop) gain, but if I do so, the system seems to become unstable. Should I configure something to set the typical loop gain or something like that to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Any sound is good for training. When you amplified the signal, you probably reached saturation and therefore the AEC became unstable.